# Shortest way to set value to variable in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

In Knockout I have observable variable `location`. It is of type `LocationEdit`. This viewModel has observable and not fields.

I have collection of field names : `fields`. For each field I want to reset values for `location`

```
fields.forEach(field => {
       if (this.uniqueField(locs, field)) {
           if (ko.isObservable(this.location()[field])) {
               this.location()[field](locs[0][field]);
           } else {
               this.location()[field] = locs[0][field];
           }
       }
});
```

To make this code more simpler (remove if-clauses), Can I somehow set value to `this.location()[field]` in one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the conditional operator (`... ? ... : ... ;`) although it doesn't change much:

```
fields.forEach(field => {
       if (this.uniqueField(locs, field)) {
           ko.isObservable(this.location()[field]) ? this.location()[field](locs[0][field]) : this.location()[field] = locs[0][field];
       }
});
```

Or you could write a function:

```
function upd(arr, index, val) {
    ko.isObservable(arr[index]) ? arr[index](val) : arr[index] = val;
}
```

Usage:

```
fields.forEach(field => {
       if (this.uniqueField(locs, field)) {
           upd(this.location(), field, locs[0][field]);
       }
});
```

See **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/vkyw9cL6/1/)**.

You could even add this function to `ko`:

```
if(typeof ko.updatePotentialObservable == 'undefined')
    ko.updatePotentialObservable = function (arr[index], val) {
        ko.isObservable(obj) ? arr[index](val) : arr[index]= val;
    }
```

Usage:

```
fields.forEach(field => {
       if (this.uniqueField(locs, field)) {
           ko.updatePotentialObservable(this.location(), field, locs[0][field]);
       }
});
```

See other **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/vkyw9cL6/2/)**

Comment: Yes, for sure, but want also to find another solution

Comment: @demo you can create your function otherwise, might come in handy in other cases (see answer update)

Comment: Quick note: your `upd` method wouldn't work, since it doesn't have access to the original object. It needs to be `function upd(obj, key, val) {
    ko.isObservable(obj[key]) ? obj[key](val) : obj[key] = val;
}`

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think [Gôtô](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456167/g%C3%B4t%C3%B4)'s answers are definitely your best options. Basically, you'd want to create a utility function similar to [`ko.unwrap`](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.js#L425) but setting a value.

But since you said "also want to find another solution", here's a different utility function. I think the most confusing part of your code is the returning calls to `locs[0][field]` and `this.location()[field]`. I'd want something with this signature:

```
reset(source, target, keys);
```

So, in your code, you could do:

```
reset(
  this.location(), 
  locs[0], 
  fields.filter(f => this.uniqueField(locs, f))
);
```

Now, writing this method, I ended up with this:

```js
const mergePropsObs = (function() {
  // Return a method for setting a specific property in object
  const getSetter = obj => prop => ko.isObservable(obj[prop])
    ? obj[prop]
    : val => obj[prop] = val;
    
  // Return unique keys for two objects
  // (I went with a quick oneliner; there are many ways to do this)
  const allKeys = (obj1, obj2) => 
    Object.keys(Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2));

  return (base, ext, onlyProps) => {
    const props = onlyProps || allKeys(base, ext);
    const values = props.map(p => ko.unwrap(ext[p]));
    
    props
      .map(getSetter(base))
      .forEach((setter, i) => setter(values[i]));
  };
}());

var base = { a: 1, b: ko.observable(2), c: 5 };

mergePropsObs(
  base, 
  { a: 2, b: 3 },
  ["a", "b"]);
  
console.log(base.a);
console.log(base.b());
console.log(base.c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

This utility method can be used with the signature mentioned above. It also has a fallback for when you don't provide an array of field names.